# AngularJS - ng-bind-html-unsafe inside a directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having the next problem. As you can see in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/ZjQPW/2/) I am trying to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` inside a template in my directive, and the attribute's value that I'm passing `item{{itemColumn.field}}` depends because is inside an ng-repeat. The thing is that I am using the ng-bind-html-unsafe in the columns that the attribute highlight is true, because the idea is to filter data (using the text input) and highlight the selection introduced by the user in the input. And as you can see, there is no value in those columns (because it seems that the binding is not working for some reason).

I have read about possible solutions and it one guy said that it can be fixed using `$compile` (which I'm actually using), so I have some time stuck in this with no idea on how to solve it.

Someone has faced something like this before? and can give me some ideas on how to solve the problem?

**EDIT**:

As Joachim suggests, I will provide more relevant code. In my template I have this

```
 <td ng-repeat=\"itemColumn in gridOptions.gridColumnDefs \" 
     ng-show=\"itemColumn.visible | elementIsDefined : itemColumn.visible : true\" >
     <div ng-switch on=\"itemColumn.highlight\"> " +
          <span ng-switch-when=\"true\">
               <div ng-bind-html-unsafe=\"item.{{itemColumn.field}} | highlight: {{gridOptions.searchInput}}\" ></div>
          </span>
          <span ng-switch-when=\"false\">{{item[itemColumn.field]}}</span>
     </div>
 </td>
```

I think my problem is related to the fact that I am trying to use a binding `{{ }}` inside the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive (Which i need). When the page renders, I got my div with the attributes as stated in the template, but the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` does not renders any HTML.

Comment: Please try to provide some minimal, relevant code in the question. Forcing everyone to go through your jsFiddle is not a good thing.

Comment: @JoachimSauer As you asked, I provide the exactly portion of the code that is giving me the issue. Thanks for the help you can give me about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you need it, i found a way to make my issue disappear. In the link function inside my directive, I added the next functions:

```
 scope.getValueToBind = function (item, subItem) {
      return item[subItem];
 };

 scope.getFieldToFilter = function () {
      var inputValue = scope.gridOptions.searchInput;
      var returnValue = $("input[ng-model='" + inputValue + "']").val();
      return returnValue;
 };
```

And in my template I call this new functions instead of having a direct binding in the ng-bind-html-unsafe (which does not work at all with internal bindings). The functions return the values that I needed (as If i had a binding)

```
 <td ng-repeat=\"itemColumn in gridOptions.gridColumnDefs \" 
     ng-show=\"itemColumn.visible | elementIsDefined : itemColumn.visible : true\" >
          <div ng-switch on=\"itemColumn.highlight\"> 
               <span ng-switch-when=\"true\"><div ng-bind-html-unsafe=\"getValueToBind(item,itemColumn.field) | highlight: getFieldToFilter()\" ></div>
               </span>
               <span ng-switch-when=\"false\">{{item[itemColumn.field]}}</span>
          </div>
</td>
```

Here you can find the complete [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/ZjQPW/4/). If you type any letter/word that is inside the table, it will be highlighted.